# Error with a exec in php

Tags: php, exec

I need to get the sso (employee number) number from the logged user in order to complete a query, but it tells me that there is an error in line 12, I can't figure out the problem can somebody help me?

```
include_once('../../include/config.inc.php');

session_start();
if($_SESSION['utype']=='Manager'){
    //Se buscan todos los datos de los empleados q pertenecen a el área lidereada por el usuario
    //Se extrae el id del jefe
    $query='select HIGH_PRIORITY userId from mgit_users.users where hrOracleNumber='.$_SESSION['sso'];
    $exec=$conn->execute ($query) or die ("Error $query".$conn->errorMsg());        
    $chiefId=$exec->fields['userId'];   
    $exec->Close();
    }
//Despliega la tabla principal
function cargar(){
    $respuesta = new xajaxResponse('ISO-8859-1');
    include('../connection/connection.php');
    //Se extrae la información de todos los records existentes
$query="SELECT HIGH_PRIORITY cc.name ccname, cc.description ccdesc, CONCAT(u.firstName,' ',u.lastName) ccowner, cc.ownerSSO osso, cc.initialBudget abudget, cc.actualBudget cbudget, cc.plannedBudget pbudget  
        FROM hr_cost_centers cc, mgit_users.users u
        WHERE cc.ownerSSO = hrOracleNumber
    ORDER BY ccname";
```

Comment: which line is line 12, and what is the error it gives you.

Comment: You are missing the closing tag of your function? `}`

Comment: is this:
$exec=$conn->execute ($query) or die ("Error $query".$conn->errorMsg()); 
and it says this:
Fatal error: Call to a member function on a non-object in /usr/local/apache/htdocs/areas/psae/psae_tools/TrainingNeedsAssesment/modules/costCentersStatus/index.php on line 12

Comment: @cheese - it's assumed he just stopped copy/paste there. he does nothing with the query either. If this is really how his file ends his problems are much greater than whatever's on line 12

Comment: This is just a part of the code.

Comment: Is it safe to assume $conn is defined in config.inc.php? ok so non object means you didn't instantiate the class. $conn is essentially undefined.

Comment: It is defined like this:

Comment: ADOLoadCode("$dbase");
$conn = ADONewConnection();
$conn->Connect("$dbhost", "$dbuser", "$dbpassword", "$dbdb");
if (!$conn){
 print 'Error: '.$conn->ErrorMsg().'<BR>';
}

Comment: @KaiQing I posted an answer to what you asked.

Comment: let's move the conversation to my answer

Answer (score 1):

This...

> Fatal error: Call to a member function on a non-object in
>   /usr/local/apache/htdocs/areas/psae/psae_tools/TrainingNeedsAssesment/modules/co‌​stCentersStatus/index.php
>   on line 12

...means that $conn is not an instance of a class at this point.
Typically instantiated by calling new on a class:

```
$conn = new databaseClass;
```

*EDIT*

This resource's example shows "Execute" and not "execute" - this may be important.
http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#ex1

so your line should perhaps be:

```
$exec=$conn->Execute($query) or die ("Error $query".$conn->errorMsg());
```

Comment: I think not because this has never happend before but I'm gonna try doing that.

Comment: I see examples of both with and without new, so I doubt that's your problem. It could be you need to call Execute and not execute. Case sensitive.

Comment: can you print_r($conn) right after your config include? it should say "object" or something similar.